# Como puedo optimizar una consulta sql!

Tags: sql, oracle

Hola buenas tardes amigos, espero y se encuentren bien, me pidieron en el trabajo que trabajara sobre esta consulta:

```
SELECT
  CAST(cd_ITVALCNV AS VARCHAR(6)) AS cd_ITVALCNV,
  cd_ICTTO,
  CAST(cd_IEMISORA AS VARCHAR(8)) AS cd_IEMISORA,
  CAST(cd_ISERIE AS   VARCHAR(8)) AS cd_ISERIE,
  cd_ICUPON,
  cd_ISUBFOL,
  cd_IFOLADM,
  CAST(nb_SORIMOV AS VARCHAR(2)) AS nb_SORIMOV,
  cd_FOPERA,
  im_CTITEXI
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      cd_ITVALCNV,
      cd_ICTTO,
      cd_IEMISORA,
      cd_ISERIE,
      cd_ICUPON,
      cd_ISUBFOL,
      cd_IFOLADM,
      nb_SORIMOV,
      FN_MAXFOPERA(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON,
      cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV) AS cd_FOPERA,
      FN_LASTCTITEXI(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON,
      cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV, FN_MAXFOPERA(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO,
      cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE, cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, cd_IFOLADM, nb_SORIMOV))
      AS im_CTITEXI
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT
          cd_ITVALCNV,
          cd_ICTTO,
          cd_IEMISORA,
          cd_ISERIE,
          cd_ICUPON,
          cd_ISUBFOL,
          CASE
            WHEN nb_SORIMOV = 'RP'
            THEN FN_MAXIFOLADM(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE,
              cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, nb_SORIMOV)
            ELSE cd_IFOLADM
          END AS cd_IFOLADM,
          nb_SORIMOV
        FROM
          TVIV023_KARCAS KC
        WHERE
          cd_ISUBFOL <> 4
      )
  )
WHERE
  im_CTITEXI <> 0
```

Dicha consulta dependen de tres funciones que son:

1)

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION FN_LASTCTITEXI (V_itvalcnv IN CHAR,
                                V_ictto    IN NUMBER,
                                V_iemisora IN CHAR,
                                V_iserie   IN CHAR,
                                V_icupon   IN NUMBER,
                                V_isubfol  IN NUMBER,
                                V_ifoladm  IN NUMBER,
                                V_sorimov  IN CHAR,
                                V_fopera   IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN FLOAT IS
v_ctitexi FLOAT;
BEGIN
  SELECT im_CTITEXI
  INTO v_ctitexi
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS id_ctitexi,
               im_CTITEXI
         FROM TVIV023_KARCAS 
         WHERE cd_ITVALCNV = V_itvalcnv
           AND cd_ICTTO    = V_ictto
           AND cd_IEMISORA = V_iemisora
           AND cd_ISERIE   = V_iserie
           AND cd_ICUPON   = V_icupon
           AND cd_ISUBFOL  = V_isubfol
           AND cd_IFOLADM  = V_ifoladm
           AND nb_SORIMOV  = V_sorimov
           AND cd_FOPERA   = V_fopera
         ORDER BY 1 DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
  RETURN v_ctitexi;
END;
```

2)

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION FN_MAXFOPERA (V_itvalcnv IN CHAR,
                              V_ictto    IN NUMBER,
                              V_iemisora IN CHAR,
                              V_iserie   IN CHAR,
                              V_icupon   IN NUMBER,
                              V_isubfol  IN NUMBER,
                              V_ifoladm  IN NUMBER,
                              V_sorimov  IN CHAR)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
v_fopera TVIV023_KARCAS.cd_FOPERA%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT Max(cd_FOPERA)
  INTO v_fopera
  FROM TVIV023_KARCAS K
  WHERE K.cd_ITVALCNV = V_itvalcnv 
    AND K.cd_ICTTO    = V_ictto    
    AND K.cd_IEMISORA = V_iemisora 
    AND K.cd_ISERIE   = V_iserie   
    AND K.cd_ICUPON   = V_icupon   
    AND K.cd_ISUBFOL  = V_isubfol
    AND K.cd_IFOLADM  = V_ifoladm
    AND K.nb_SORIMOV  = V_sorimov;
  RETURN v_fopera;
END;
```

3)

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION FN_MAXIFOLADM (V_itvalcnv IN CHAR,
                               V_ictto    IN NUMBER,
                               V_iemisora IN CHAR,
                               V_iserie   IN CHAR,
                               V_icupon   IN NUMBER,
                               V_isubfol  IN NUMBER,
                               V_sorimov  IN CHAR)
RETURN NUMBER IS
v_ifoladm NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT Max(cd_IFOLADM)
  INTO v_ifoladm
  FROM TVIV023_KARCAS K
  WHERE K.cd_ITVALCNV = V_itvalcnv 
    AND K.cd_ICTTO    = V_ictto    
    AND K.cd_IEMISORA = V_iemisora 
    AND K.cd_ISERIE   = V_iserie   
    AND K.cd_ICUPON   = V_icupon   
    AND K.cd_ISUBFOL  = V_isubfol  
    AND K.nb_SORIMOV  = V_sorimov  
    AND K.cd_FREG     = (SELECT Max(cd_FREG)
                         FROM TVIV023_KARCAS D
                         WHERE D.cd_ITVALCNV = V_itvalcnv 
                           AND D.cd_ICTTO    = V_ictto    
                           AND D.cd_IEMISORA = V_iemisora 
                           AND D.cd_ISERIE   = V_iserie   
                           AND D.cd_ICUPON   = V_icupon   
                           AND D.cd_ISUBFOL  = V_isubfol  
                           AND D.nb_SORIMOV  = V_sorimov);
  RETURN v_ifoladm;
END;
```

La problemática es que se tarda demasiado en terminar la consulta, quería saber si me pueden ayudar en brindarme propuestas de como puedo optimar la consulta sin modificar si es posible la sentencias, la verdad no conozco mucho de base de datos, pero me dan propuestas de como solucionar este problema estaria bien agradecido, quedo al pendiente amigos, saludos y excelente tarde.

Nota: Solo se usa una tabla y ya probe con usar indices y hacerlo todo de manera local creando la tabla y haciendo las funciones pero aun asi no se puede.

En el plan de ejecucion me arroja esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Practicamente los indices no los toma en cuenta y se lo asigne en este campo cd_ISUBFO y el ejemplo que mande lo hice desde un usuario que no tiene privilegios para agregar indices,

DE REGISTROS SON: 48582

Otra cosa es que por lo mismo de que tarda bastante no se exactamente cuanto, lo que si he visto es tarda mas de 1 hora y asi sigue. :(

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos saber que indices tiene la tabla, y un explainplan de la consulta. para ver que partes tardan mas y que se puede optimizar

Comment: tambien la cantidad de registros afectados y cuanto tiempo tarda.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya actualice mi pregunta con el plan de ejecucion.

Comment: Y como tal no tengo un tiempo estimado de lo que tarda, ya que las veces que he ejecutado la consulta no ha terminado y esto lleva horas y asi que mejor opto por detener la ejecucion XD

Comment: LOS REGISTROS SON: 48582 y hace la busqueda en toda la tabla completa

Answer (score 4):

Antes de nada entiende que todo lo que te ponga es orientativo porque no puedo ejecutar pruebas para saber el rendimiento, pero quizás te sirva de guía.

La principal razón de tus tiempos tan altos es que **estás ejecutando muchas (demasiadas) subselects**, tanto en la propia select original,la cual has subdividido en 3, como en cada una de las funciones que vas llamando a lo largo del código y de las cuales algunas van dentro de otras funciones. *Al final tienes al programa dando vueltas sobre una misma tabla una y otra vez cuando lo lógico sería tener como mucho un par de subselects a lo sumo.*

Por ello creo para empezar, un buen objetivo a alcanzar es que tu query parezca a algo tal que así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(cd_ITVALCNV AS VARCHAR(6)) AS cd_ITVALCNV,
                CD_ICTTO,
                CAST(cd_IEMISORA AS VARCHAR(8)) AS cd_IEMISORA,
                CD_ISERIE,
                CD_ICUPON,
                CD_ISUBFIL,
                CASE
                  WHEN nb_SORIMOV = 'RP'
                  THEN FN_MAXIFOLADM(cd_ITVALCNV, cd_ICTTO, cd_IEMISORA, cd_ISERIE,
                    cd_ICUPON, cd_ISUBFOL, nb_SORIMOV)
                  ELSE cd_IFOLADM
                END AS cd_IFOLADM,
                CAST(nb_SORIMOV AS VARCHAR(2)) AS nb_SORIMOV,
                Max(cd_FOPERA) AS cd_FOPERA,
                im_CTITEXI AS im_CTITEXI
FROM TVI023_KARCAS KC
WHERE im_CTITEXI <> 0 AND cd_ISUBFOL <>4;
```

Lo que he hecho:

- Condenso las 3 subqueries iniciales en 1 sola.
- Elimino la funcion 2 llamada FN_MAXFOPERA que al final lo único que hace es traer Max(cd_FOPERA), lo cual puedes hacerlo directamente en la query.

Como ves, todo el código queda condensado en una sola query, por lo que así optimizas los tiempos de ejecución al no tener una query que depende de otra que a su vez depende de otra.

Con respecto a la funcion 1 y 3 no me queda muy claro que pretendes conseguir con ellas, pues al final estas igualando los códigos de todas las columnas en sus respectivos where, lo cual te deja con el elemento inicial que pretendías obtener.

Por ultimo, y quizás la clave para solucionar el problema: **¿Es obligado que todo se encuentre en una sola query?** A mi parecer creo que usando un **PROCEDURE** y segmentar el cálculo de datos es lo mas conveniente. Sobretodo intentaría separar las funciones de la SELECT principal.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya ando tomando de ejemplo tu respuesta, estoy creando todo en subconsultas, que prácticamente estoy deshaciendo me de las funciones y metiéndolas en una consulta, cuando termine pondré todo el query y vean cómo quedó al final, te agradezco, que hayas respondido a mi pregunta, te mando un gran saludo y buena vibra :)

Answer (score 0):

Que onda amigos, aqui paso a dejar mi granito de arena con la consulta ya terminada:

```
WITH max_cd_freg_t AS (
    SELECT
        cd_itvalcnv,
        cd_ictto,
        cd_iemisora,
        cd_iserie,
        cd_icupon,
        cd_isubfol,
        nb_sorimov,
        MAX(cd_freg) AS max_cd_freg
    FROM
        tviv023_karcas
    GROUP BY
        cd_itvalcnv,
        cd_ictto,
        cd_iemisora,
        cd_iserie,
        cd_icupon,
        cd_isubfol,
        nb_sorimov
),qdistinct AS (
    SELECT
        a.cd_itvalcnv,
        a.cd_ictto,
        a.cd_iemisora,
        a.cd_iserie,
        a.cd_icupon,
        a.cd_isubfol,
        a.nb_sorimov,
        a.cd_freg,
        MAX(cd_ifoladm) fn_maxifoladm
    FROM
        tviv023_karcas a
        JOIN max_cd_freg_t b ON a.cd_itvalcnv = b.cd_itvalcnv
                                AND a.cd_ictto = b.cd_ictto
                                AND a.cd_iemisora = b.cd_iemisora
                                AND a.cd_iserie = b.cd_iserie
                                AND a.cd_icupon = b.cd_icupon
                                AND a.cd_isubfol = b.cd_isubfol
                                AND a.nb_sorimov = b.nb_sorimov
                                AND a.cd_freg = b.max_cd_freg
    GROUP BY
        a.cd_itvalcnv,
        a.cd_ictto,
        a.cd_iemisora,
        a.cd_iserie,
        a.cd_icupon,
        a.cd_isubfol,
        a.nb_sorimov,
        a.cd_freg
),select_fnmaxfopera AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        kc.cd_itvalcnv,
        kc.cd_ictto,
        kc.cd_iemisora,
        kc.cd_iserie,
        kc.cd_icupon,
        kc.cd_isubfol,
        CASE
                WHEN kc.nb_sorimov = 'RP' THEN c.fn_maxifoladm
                ELSE kc.cd_ifoladm
            END
        AS cd_ifoladm,
        kc.nb_sorimov
    FROM
        tviv023_karcas kc
        JOIN qdistinct c ON kc.cd_itvalcnv = c.cd_itvalcnv
                            AND kc.cd_ictto = c.cd_ictto
                            AND kc.cd_iemisora = c.cd_iemisora
                            AND kc.cd_iserie = c.cd_iserie
                            AND kc.cd_icupon = c.cd_icupon
                            AND kc.cd_isubfol = c.cd_isubfol
                            AND kc.nb_sorimov = c.nb_sorimov
    WHERE
        kc.cd_isubfol <> 4     
           --and kc.nb_sorimov <> 'RP'     
),select_fn_maxofopera AS (
    SELECT
        cd_itvalcnv,
        cd_ictto,
        cd_iemisora,
        cd_iserie,
        cd_icupon,
        cd_isubfol,
        cd_ifoladm,
        nb_sorimov,
        MAX(cd_fopera) AS fn_maxfopera
    FROM
        tviv023_karcas
    WHERE
        cd_isubfol <> 4
    GROUP BY
        cd_itvalcnv,
        cd_ictto,
        cd_iemisora,
        cd_iserie,
        cd_icupon,
        cd_isubfol,
        cd_ifoladm,
        nb_sorimov
    ORDER BY
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8
),union_distinct_y_maxofpera AS (
    SELECT
        v.cd_itvalcnv,
        v.cd_ictto,
        v.cd_iemisora,
        v.cd_iserie,
        v.cd_icupon,
        v.cd_isubfol,
        v.cd_ifoladm,
        v.nb_sorimov,
        v.fn_maxfopera AS cd_fopera,
        fn_lastctitexi(v.cd_itvalcnv,v.cd_ictto,v.cd_iemisora,v.cd_iserie,v.cd_icupon,v.cd_isubfol,v.cd_ifoladm,v.nb_sorimov,v.fn_maxfopera
) AS im_ctitexi
    FROM
        select_fnmaxfopera x
        JOIN select_fn_maxofopera v ON x.cd_itvalcnv = v.cd_itvalcnv
                                       AND x.cd_ictto = v.cd_ictto
                                       AND x.cd_iemisora = v.cd_iemisora
                                       AND x.cd_iserie = v.cd_iserie
                                       AND x.cd_icupon = v.cd_icupon
                                       AND x.cd_isubfol = v.cd_isubfol
                                       AND x.cd_ifoladm = v.cd_ifoladm
                                       AND x.nb_sorimov = v.nb_sorimov
) SELECT
    CAST(cd_itvalcnv AS VARCHAR(6) ) cd_itvalcnv,
    cd_ictto,
    CAST(cd_iemisora AS VARCHAR(8) ) cd_iemisora,
    CAST(cd_iserie AS VARCHAR(8) ) cd_iserie,
    cd_icupon,
    cd_isubfol,
    cd_ifoladm,
    CAST(nb_sorimov AS VARCHAR(2) ) AS nb_sorimov,
    cd_fopera,
    im_ctitexi
  FROM
    union_distinct_y_maxofpera
  WHERE
    im_ctitexi <> 0
```

Saludos y buena vibra.

Comment: ¿Mejoró el rendimiento?

Comment: Si, mejoró bastante :)